# is it possible for a son to inherit an allele on a Y chromosome?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, allele

Obviously, the only way for one to be male is to inherit the Y chromosome, but are there alleles on the y chromosomes? Or is it just automatically the recessive trait without an allele.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testis-determining_factor this might be a good start for your own investication

Answer (score 0):

The question `are there alleles on the y chromosomes` is unclear. Here are two possible things you might mean

- Is there genetic variation among individuals on the y chromosomes
- Is there anything functional on the Y chromosome

> Is there genetic variation among individuals on the y chromosomes

Yes, of course, there is genetic variation of the Y chromosome just like there is genetic variation other chromosomes. Talking about SNPs (Single Nucleotide Polymorphism) only, we have already detected tens of thousands of SNPs on the Y chromosome (see [this page](https://isogg.org/wiki/Y-DNA_SNP_testing_chart)).

> Is there anything functional on the Y chromosome

Yes! As an example, one of the most famous gene on the Y chromosome is the Test determination factor (as already indicated in a comment by @L.Diagio).